# Postman application- extension from chrome is written in which language?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, postman

This could be layman question. I use the postman application which i got from the chrome extension. It was soo good. I really want to know in which language it is written? Is it written completely in javascript and packaged using some tools like cardova? Or any native language is used? [image: postman app]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a "chrome app" written in HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript. 
[About Chrome apps](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)

Google through Chrome allows this application to run in a native container that work on any operating system example: Mac OS, Linux.

In order to publish the app , developers can package and upload the app source files to chrome web store. refer the link for further details

Answer (score 5):

Check the `Postman Legacy` Repo which is available in GitHub.
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-chrome-extension-legacy/tree/develop/chrome

They used the following technologies

JS Framework: AngularJS
CSS Framework: Bootstrap
Template Engine: Handlebar
DOM: jQuery, jQuery UI and many more jQuery Plugins.
Other: vkBeautify, Underscore and many more.

> In General about Chrome Extension. This is chrome plugin which is built with manifest.json (Configuration file) and Chrome API.

You can include your HTML, JS and other JS Library or Framework as per your Extension Scope.

How to build the Chrome Plugin ?

**1. Enable Developer Mode**
[image]

**2. Load your extension**
[image]

**Finally once you are done with extension development, you can pack it as CRX file to upload it to Chrome Web Store through pack extension button**